# Django con PyInstaller

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller

Estimados, estoy tratando de compilar a .exe Django con PyInstaller. La instalación de Django y PyInstaller esta bien, cuando compilo también lo hace bien:

```
$ pyinstaller --name=mysite mysite/manage.py
```

Pero el problema esta cuando quiero ejecutar el .exe que obtuve con PyInstaller:

```
ejecutable.exe runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Me sale este error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000000004BF8B70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
  File "site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
  File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
  File "site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
  File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
  File "site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
  File "site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
  File "site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.messages.apps'
```

Estoy buscando la solución pero no hay nada en concreto sobre este error, comprendo que puede ser parte de PyInstaller, es decir que en el momento de compilar, no tuvo en cuenta ese paquete.
No puedo encontrar la solucion a este error para se ejecute el .exe sin ningún problema.

Comment: No se exactamente como funciona PyInstaler ni si es posible hacer lo que tu quieres. Pero tu problema es claramente que PyInstaler no esta tomando en cuenta ciertos paquetes. Deberis buscar la manera de añadir los paquetes de los que se vaya quejando en el momento de generar el exe.

Comment: @Zartch gracias por tu respuesta, logre solucionar el problema, pero instalando python 3.5. Ahora surge otro que describo en el siguiente enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71350/standalone-con-django . Cuando ejecuto el .exe se abre y cierra rápidamente la ventana del binario, no se ejecuta el servidor 127.0.0.1:8000 y tampoco puedo ver ningún error para poder solucionar el problema.